# MVC5: Pass child entity to Create (post method)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, parent-child

I created an application to guide the user through some data collection processes. He has an entity 'customer', adding different datasets in different views.

At the end, I want to show him an overview where he can also add a comment. The comment is saved in another table as child entity connected by a foreign key.
Is there any way to create a child entity from the viewmodel in this form?

This is my parent entity Customer.

```
public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "FamilyName", ResourceType = typeof(TextResourceFile))]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(TextResourceFile))]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "PostalCode", ResourceType = typeof(TextResourceFile))]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "City", ResourceType = typeof(TextResourceFile))]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "StreetAndNumber", ResourceType = typeof(TextResourceFile))]
        public string StreetAndNumber { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "BirthDate", ResourceType = typeof(TextResourceFile))]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "CreationDate", ResourceType = typeof(TextResourceFile))]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "ModificationDate", ResourceType = typeof(TextResourceFile))]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CustomerNote> CustomerNotes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<somethingElse> somethingElse{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<somethingElse> somethingElse{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<somethingElse> somethingElse{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<somethingElse> somethingElse{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<somethingElse> somethingElse{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<somethingElse> somethingElse{ get; set; }
    }
```

This is my child CustomerNote

```
public class CustomerNote
{
    [Key]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public int CustomerCode { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Anamnesis", ResourceType = typeof(TextResourceFile))]
    public string Anamnesis { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my initial Create() Methode where I have all the necessary data:

```
    public ActionResult Create(int? code)
    {
        if (code == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var customer = db.Customer.FirstOrDefault(cu => cu.Code == code);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        ViewBag.Customercode = customer.Code;

        var customNote = new CustomerNote();

        customNote.CustomerCode = customer.Code;
        customNote.Anamnesis = string.Empty;
        customer.CustomerNotes.Add(customNote);

        return View(customer);
    }
```

And here is my Post Method, where I want to save the comment:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(/*[Bind(Include = "CustomerNote")] */Customer customer)
    {
        if (customer != null && customer.CustomerNotes != null)
        {
            var customerNote = new CustomerNote();

            customerNote.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
            customerNote.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
            customerNote.CustomerCode = customer.Code;
            customerNote.Anamnesis = customer.CustomerNotes.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate).FirstOrDefault().Anamnesis;

            db.CustomerNote.Add(customerNote);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(customer);
    }
```

In my view I'm showing the data as follows, but of course that is not working. How do I have to change it?

```
<br />
<h3>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerNotes.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate).FirstOrDefault().Anamnesis)</h3>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerNotes.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate).FirstOrDefault(), new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerNotes.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate).FirstOrDefault().Anamnesis, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
</div>
```

I added now a viewmodel:

```
public class CustomerNoteIndexData
{
    public int CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public CustomerNote CustomerNote { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public otherInformationLists otherInformationLists { get; set; }
    public otherInformationLists otherInformationLists { get; set; }
    public otherInformationLists otherInformationLists { get; set; }
    public otherInformationLists otherInformationLists { get; set; }
    public otherInformationLists otherInformationLists { get; set; }
    public otherInformationLists otherInformationLists { get; set; }

}
```

They're not lists, but show the latest entry for each entity.

Now somehow the CustomerCode stays empty.

Comment: Your editing data so always use a view model. It will contain properties from your `Customer` data model, and properties from your `CustomerNote` that you need in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: I'm using now a viewmodel instead of the whole "customer". Now I can at least access the CustomerNote in the View, but the customercode stays empty. How can I make sure the viewmodel returns the values I'm giving inside in the first create method?

Comment: View models DO NOT contain data models! They contain only the properties of the data models you need in the view (and I have no idea what `CustomerCode` is, or how you set its value, or bind it in the view or POST method. And the only property of `Customer` that should be submitted in your form to create the note is the ID of the customer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My Code is basically my ID, I added it to the viewmodel, now it works.